# spark can't call hive udf. Error in query: Undefined function: 'myh6

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Error in query:

> Undefined function: 'myh6'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 7.

When I've already used `def hive udf` in spark, it tells me the `hive udf` is not found. I've found the spark driver is not loading the `resource_uri jar`.  So it can not use the hive `udf`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the HiveContext to connect Hive. Like workaround (if you have not created the function as permanent in Hive), You would try create a temporary function in the HiveContext how is suggested here

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.0/bk_spark-guide/content/calling-udfs.html